# Linear transformations and T-invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

A nontrivial, T-*invariant* subspace is one in which the subspace, $W$ is not equal to the zero subspace or the entire subspace. 
If $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation, then is it always the case that there will be nontrivial, T-invariant subspace?

I showed that the range of $T$, $R(T)$, and the null space of $T$, $N(T)$, are T-invariant subspaces. So, this would imply that there are always nontrivial, T-invariant subspaces, right?

Also, if I let $T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be defined by $T((x,y))=(y,x)$, then would the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$, be two nontrivial, T-invariant subspaces?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider $T((x,y)) = (-y,x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, so $y=-x$ wouldn't be a T-invariant subspace?

Comment: Right, that one has only $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ as invariant subspaces.

Comment: @DanielFischer So the line, $y=x$ (with either both positive or both negative) wouldn't work?

Comment: I ask because I'm supposed to fine 2 distinct nontrivial, T-invariant subspaces. So I'm guessing there must be, but I can't think of anything else

Comment: There need not exist nontrivial (meaning neither $\{0\}$ nor $V$) invariant subspaces in general. The rotations of a plane (if the angle isn't a multiple of $\pi$) are examples for that. What _exactly_ are you supposed to find? What constraints on $V$ or the scalar field?

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, I see what you mean. And, I'm supposed to find two distinct nontrivial, T-invariant subspaces for $T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ defined by $T((x,y))=(y,x)$.

Comment: For that specific $T$, you have found the two nontrivial invariant subspaces. They are what you wrote in the question. My point was "So, this would imply that there are always nontrivial, T-invariant subspaces, right?" is wrong, there need not always be. For the specific transformation $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$, there are.